Videojs - changing control buttons appearance
I need to replave buttons images on control bar with ours.
Hi,
I am kind of new to the subject of videojs.
There are a lot of messages regarding adding buttons or changing control bar, but I cound not find how one actually can replace the "image" or "character" on the button itself. From one of the messages I understood that default look comes from the icon font.
Still, what I am to do in order to replace it with other image or character?
Thanks in advance

Looks like you can reskin the player to look how you want it to.
